# Javascript Regular Expressions - Capturing strings that are preceded by another string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use Javascript regular expressions to extract some variable values from a URL. The URL takes the following pattern:

`@companyname/dl-molecularType-componentName`.

An example URL is:

`@companyname/dl-atoms-link`

I would like to use one RegEx to extract the molecularType and componentName from the URL to give me an array:

`['atoms', 'link']`

Here's what I have tried, using the brilliant [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) site:

RegEx:

`/(@company\/dl+-)+(?!\1)/g`

My idea being that the first capture group would capture `@companyname/dl-` and the second would capture everything which isn't in the first group. However RegExr seems to suggest this would return the same results as the first capture group. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Why a regular expression and not `.split(/[/-]/).slice(-2)`

Comment: You might want to try something like `@companyname\/dl-([^\/-]+)-([^\/-]+)`, or `@companyname\/dl-([^\/-]+)-([^\/-]+)$`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gndmD7/1).

Comment: `"@companyname/dl-atoms-link".split("-").slice(-2)`

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribitzew. Thanks for the advice. However your demo only seems to work in PHP. If I try it in Javascript it only returns the entire URL.

Comment: It works everywhere, you just need to get the values in the capturing groups. See [this JS demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/sap923j5/)

Comment: Ah I see the error of my ways now. Thanks Wiktor!

Answer (score 1):

You can use somethign like the following (note that we know the structure and can fine tune the regex better):

```js
function extract_fields(url)
{
   var match = url.match(/@[^\/]+\/dl-([^-]+)-(\w+)/);
   if ( match ) {
    return {molecularType: match[1], componentName: match[2]};
   }
   return false;
}

console.log(extract_fields('@companyname/dl-molecularType-componentName'));
console.log(extract_fields('@companyname/dl-atoms-link'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are using right now is a negative lookahead `(?!\1)`. It basically means "is not **followed** by the same I had on the first capturing group", but it doesn't capture it.

If both variables are always words+numbers you can use `\w` (it's equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

Try:

```js
let regex = /(@companyname\/dl-)(\w+)-(\w+)/;
let testCases = [
  "@companyname/dl-molecularType-componentName",
  "@companyname/dl-atoms-link"
];

testCases.forEach(
  str => {
    let match = str.match(regex);
    console.log('Whole match: ', match[0]);
    console.log('Molecular Type: ', match[2]);
    console.log('Component Name: ', match[3]);
  }
)
```

Comment: That just seems to return the entire URL, rather than an array of its parts

Comment: My bad, discard the `g` flag. Gonna edit my answer to make it easy

Answer (score 0):

In your regex, you don't have to capture the start of the string in a capturing group `(@company\/dl+-)+` and you don't have to repeat it using `+` because it occurs only once. The `(?!\1)` part is a negative lookahead and is an assertion which does not consume any characters.

Another option to get your values could to be more precise about what you would allow to match using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-z]` which you can extend to have it match more than a-z and make the match case insensitive using the `/i` flag.

Capture your matches in 2 capturing groups and from the result remove the first items which contains the full match:

```js
[
  "@companyname/dl-molecularType-componentName",
  "@companyname/dl-atoms-link"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.match(/@companyname\/dl-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/i).slice(1));
});
```